# What could be the cause of these resin prints looking wonky?

Tags: troubleshooting, resin

I don't know how to describe it, but when I print on my Phrozen Sonic Mini with this resin, this happens (it's Siraya tech, but it happens with regular resin too). The bottom half, the stuff furthest from the build plate gets wonky looking. The first picture, the print supposed to have a flat bottom, but it bulges out, and it has to be round, but it's not perfectly round. I printed it at a 45° angle, and it used a ton of supports, and 3.5  seconds exposure per layer.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might be a problem with the structure and orientation of the print - if you print large flat areas in one go, the still malleable resin can get sucked at and deform, the next layer then reinforcing the deformed state and thus creating the odd bulging pattern.

You might want to tilt the printed parts so that the flat areas are printed at some angle and thus reducing the area on which forces are applied on layer change.